# How to Combine Two Bar Plots into one Using GGPlot

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

I am trying to combine two different bar graphs into one using GGPLOT.
Seperately the code is `

```
ggplot(data=by_div_salaries, aes(x=women_salary, y=salaries.ClassificationName)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +labs(title = "Women Head Coach Salaries")

ggplot(data=by_div_salaries, aes(x=men_salary, y=salaries.ClassificationName)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +labs(title = "Men Head Coach Salaries")
```

and I am trying to get the mens salary next to the womens salary by having two bars for each ClassificationName.

I tried this:

```
ggplot(data=by_div_salaries, aes()) + 
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x=women_salary, y=salaries.ClassificationName), position=position_nudge(x = 0.2), width=0.2,stat = "identity",color="green" ) +
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x=men_salary, y=salaries.ClassificationName), position=position_nudge(x = -0.2), width=.2, stat = "identity", color = "blue") + 
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Division") +
  xlab("Salary")
```

But am getting this error:
`Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale`

```
I want the two grpahs next to each other.
```

Comment: Try with `scale_y_discrete` instead of `scale_y_continuous`. My guess is that `salaries.ClassificationName` is a catagorical column.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a situation where reshaped ("longer") data would probably be easier to work with.

```
library(tidyverse)
by_div_salaries %>%
  pivot_longer(c(women_salary, men_salary)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=value, y=salaries.ClassificationName, fill = name)) + 
  geom_col()
```